# Compare column in two workbooks and paste if same value exist

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, if-statement, range

below you can see code that I am using to compare two workbooks and if identical value is found in Workbook 1 and Workbook 2 in column 71 then the data between columns 30-35 from workbook 1 should be brought into columns 30-35 in workbook 2. Otherwise do nothing.

Currently the code is working partly, as it runs but brings values mostly from wrong rows when the condition is met. I haven't been able to find the reason for it. I would appreciate suggestions what might cause this issue.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long
Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, arr3 As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lRow3 As Long
Dim lRow4 As Long


Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("file1")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("file2")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)

wb1.Activate
ws1.Select 

Range("BO7").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("BP7").NumberFormat = "@"
lRow3 = Range("BO" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 7 To lRow3
    Cells(i, 71).NumberFormat = "@"
    Cells(i, 71) = Cells(i, 67) & Cells(i, 68)
Next i

wb2.Activate
ws2.Select

Range("BO7").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("BP7").NumberFormat = "@"
lRow4 = Range("BO" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 7 To lRow4
    Cells(i, 71).NumberFormat = "@"
    Cells(i, 71) = Cells(i, 67) & Cells(i, 68)
Next i

ws1.Activate
Range("BS6").Value = "Reference"
ws2.Activate
Range("BS6").Value = "Reference"
 
LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ws1.Activate
arr1 = ws1.Range("A6:BS" & LastRow1)
arr2 = ws2.Range("A6:BS" & LastRow2)

For i = 7 To UBound(arr1)
    For j = 7 To UBound(arr2)
        If arr1(i, 71) = arr2(j, 71) Then
            
            arr2(j, 30) = arr1(i, 30)
            arr2(j, 31) = arr1(i, 31)
            arr2(j, 32) = arr1(i, 32)
            arr2(j, 33) = arr1(i, 33)
            arr2(j, 34) = arr1(i, 34)
            arr2(j, 35) = arr1(i, 35)

        End If
    Next j
Next i

ReDim arr3(6 To UBound(arr2), 1 To 6)
For i = 6 To UBound(arr2)
    arr3(i, 1) = arr2(i, 30)
    arr3(i, 2) = arr2(i, 31)
    arr3(i, 3) = arr2(i, 32)
    arr3(i, 4) = arr2(i, 33)
    arr3(i, 5) = arr2(i, 34)
    arr3(i, 6) = arr2(i, 35)
Next i

ws2.Range("AD7:AI" & LastRow2) = arr3
```

Comment: What are the values being joined here `Cells(i, 67) & Cells(i, 68)`. Maybe add a separator otherwise `"AB" & "C"`  will be the same as `"A" & "BC"`.

Comment: They are numbers but converted to text as I need to maintain that also leading zeros are remaining. They were showing up correctly in my previous code but thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next updated code. It is based on what I supposed you dried doing. The last iteration is not necessary, but I tried letting the code like it is. I mean, arr3 could be loaded in the previous one. Besides that, activating, selecting only consumes Excel resources without bringing any benefit:

```
Sub copyFromTwoWorkbooks()
 Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
 Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, arr3 As Variant
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, lRow3 As Long, lRow4 As Long


Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("file1")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("file2")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1): Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)

ws1.Range("BO7").NumberFormat = "@": ws1.Range("BP7").NumberFormat = "@"

lRow3 = ws1.Range("BO" & ws1.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
ws1.Range("BS7:BS" & lRow3).NumberFormat = "@"

For i = 7 To lRow3
    ws1.cells(i, 71) = ws1.cells(i, 67).Value & ws1.cells(i, 68).Value
Next i

ws2.Range("BO7").NumberFormat = "@": ws2.Range("BP7").NumberFormat = "@"

lRow4 = ws2.Range("BO" & ws2.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
ws2.Range("BS7:BS" & lRow4).NumberFormat = "@"
For i = 7 To lRow4
    ws2.cells(i, 71) = ws2.cells(i, 67) & ws2.cells(i, 68)
Next i

ws1.Range("BS6").Value = "Reference": ws2.Range("BS6").Value = "Reference"

LastRow1 = ws1.cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
LastRow2 = ws2.cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

arr1 = ws1.Range("A6:BS" & LastRow1).Value
arr2 = ws2.Range("A6:BS" & LastRow2).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr2)
        If arr1(i, 71) = arr2(j, 71) Then
            arr2(j, 30) = arr1(i, 30)
            arr2(j, 31) = arr1(i, 31)
            arr2(j, 32) = arr1(i, 32)
            arr2(j, 33) = arr1(i, 33)
            arr2(j, 34) = arr1(i, 34)
            arr2(j, 35) = arr1(i, 35)
            Exit For 'exiting the loop after finding a match
        End If
    Next j
Next i

ReDim arr3(1 To UBound(arr2), 1 To 6)
For i = 1 To UBound(arr2)
    arr3(i, 1) = arr2(i, 30)
    arr3(i, 2) = arr2(i, 31)
    arr3(i, 3) = arr2(i, 32)
    arr3(i, 4) = arr2(i, 33)
    arr3(i, 5) = arr2(i, 34)
    arr3(i, 6) = arr2(i, 35)
Next i

ws2.Range("AD7").Resize(UBound(arr3), UBound(arr3, 2)).Value = arr3
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for this helpful piece of code @FaneDuru it really helped me to the right tracks. Regardless there is still something fundamentally incorrect in my own data as it is not giving me the correct values in columns 30-35. 

Also I have to admit that I am not used to arrays which can be also an issue. Could you please enlighten me what is happening here:

```ws2.Range("AD7").Resize(UBound(arr3), UBound(arr3, 2)).Value = arr3```¨?

Comment: @Meettu When you paste from clipboard, it is enough to supply the cell address where the range to be pasted. In case of dropping a content of an array you have to supply the correct dimensions (rows and columns) of the array. `UBound(arr3)` returns the array rows number and `UBound(arr3, 2))` do the same for columns.

Comment: Yes thank you. I have now looked more into arrays and still need some practice in order get my code working. 

I believe that I have to also use Redim reserve statement in order store the values that I go through in the loops.  For instance in below:

   <For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr2)
    If arr1(i, 71) = arr2(j, 71) Then
    arr2(j, 30) = arr1(i, 30)
    arr2(j, 31) = arr1(i, 31)>

Comment: Yes thank you. I have now looked more into arrays and still need some practice in order get my code working. 

I believe that I have to also use Redim reserve statement in order store the values that I go through in the loops.  Now I am losing me values when they are getting pasted to the new file. For instance in below:

```ReDim arr3(1 To UBound(arr2), 1 To 6)
For i = 1 To UBound(arr2)
    arr3(i, 1) = arr2(i, 30)
    arr3(i, 2) = arr2(i, 31)
    arr3(i, 3) = arr2(i, 32)
    arr3(i, 4) = arr2(i, 33)
    arr3(i, 5) = arr2(i, 34)
    arr3(i, 6) = arr2(i, 35)
Next i```

Comment: @Meettu I am afraid I cannot get you... I do  not understand what you want. In principle, `ReDim Preserve` too often is not a good way to handle the memory. I mean, if you are able to initially determine/calculate the necessary array dimensions, **you should do it** and avoid `ReDim Preserve`. Now, `ReDim Preserve` can change **only the second dimension** (the array columns). The best idea is to initially `ReDim` it in a way to be sure that it will be equal or larger then the necessary  second dimension. And use only one time `ReDim Preserve`, **after iteration**, using the iteration variable.

Comment: @Meettu If nothing confidential in your workbook, now, for some minutes I have some available time and if you share it, **clearly explaining what you try doing** and having the code you tries, I can try helping. But your way of coming here from three to three days is not the most appropriate way when you need help...